# Poor performing loops - is there a better solution than loops?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to speed up a stored procedure I have.

I have a table where I need to update a value based on the line before. (sound easy) however the complication comes in in that this data is based on a part number which fits X number of Items and there are so many items in a country.

Example data:

```
 id Part Item       Country Year Count
1   ABC   Bike      usa     2022  500
2   ABC   Bike      usa     2023  (500- n)
3   ABC   Bike      usa     2024  (500 - n - m)
4   ABC   Scooter   usa     2022  400
5   ABC   Scooter   usa     2023  (400- n)
6   ABC   Scooter   usa     2024  (400 - n - m)
7   ABC   Bike      uk      2022  600
8   ABC   Bike      uk      2023  (600- e)
9   ABC   Bike      uk      2024  (600 - e - f)
10  ABC   Lawnmower uk      2022  200
11  ABC   Lawnmower uk      2023  (200- e)
12  ABC   Lawnmower uk      2024  (200 - e - f)
```

So my code so far looks like this:

```
    declare @ic int, @il as int, @iv as varchar(20)  --declared variables for loops
    declare @nvio as int , @c as int , @lc1 as int
    DECLARE @ART VARCHAR(50),@LOC VARCHAR(10)
    declare @vs varchar(250)
    set  @vs = ''
 
    drop table if exists #T_k
    create table #T_k ( id int identity(1,1), I [varchar](20),Part[varchar](50),Country [VARCHAR] 
    (50))
    create clustered index on #T_K (Country,I,Part)
    
        insert into #T_k(I, Part,Country)
        select Item,Part,Country
        from  [Product_lifecycle_Europe].[dbo].[TBL_cte_Data]  
        group by Item, Part,Country
        order by Country,Item,Part

    select @ic = @@ROWCOUNT
    select @il = 1

        while @il <= @ic begin
             
           select  @iv = I ,@ART=Part, @LOC= country
           from #T_k 
           where id = @il
           set @lc1 = 1
           select @c = MAX (rn) 
           from [Product_lifecycle_Europe].[dbo].[TBL_cte_Data]-  --this is to find the maximum                    rownumber of an item per country
           where country = @loc AND Part = @ART
-- So now I find the current Count of Items per country by part
                while @lc1 <= @c begin
                  select @nvio = PredictiveVIO  from [Product_lifecycle_Europe].[dbo]. 
                  [TBL_cte_Data] where rn = @lc1 and Item = @iv and Country = @loc 
                  
                  update [Product_lifecycle_Europe].[dbo].[TBL_cte_Data]
                  set [Original VIO] = @nvio,PredictiveVIO =  @nvio * scrap  
                  from   [Product_lifecycle_Europe].[dbo].[TBL_cte_Data] 
                  inner join [dbo].[Tbl_Mycountry_Codes] mcc on mcc.Country = [TBL_cte_Data].Country
                  where rn = (@lc1 + 1) and Item = @iv   
  
                  set @lc1 = @lc1 + 1  -- this is for the inner loop (Part Number by Item per country) by Year 
                end 
            set @il = @il + 1 --this is for the outer loop Next Item
            end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops tend to be slow so if you can avoid them you should (check out Jeff Moden's RBAR row-by-agonizing-row) for more explanation. Instead you want to use set based queries whenever possible.

The idea with the below code is to join the "Parts" table to itself so you can get a tally for all previous years. From there the outer query will subtract the current count from the previous years totals. I replicated what you had above for the Parts table but changed the count values.

```
select
    id
    ,Part
    ,Item
    ,Country
    ,[Year]
    ,[Count]
    ,Tally
    ,[Count]-lag(Tally) OVER(Partition By Item,Country Order By [Year]) as RemainingCount 
FROM (
        select 
            sum(b.[Count]) as Tally 
            ,a.[Year]
            ,a.Item
            ,a.Country
            ,a.Part
            ,a.Count
            ,a.id
        FROM PartsTable a
        JOIN PartsTable b on b.Item = a.Item and a.Country = b.Country 
                                    and b.[Year] between a.[Year]-100 and a.[Year]
        Group by
            a.Item
            ,a.Country
            ,a.Part
            ,a.[Year]
            ,a.[Count]
            ,a.id
) tal
Order By id
```

This code produces a result like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution I came up with. I did not need the lag function as I just wanted to update the count column. So my join was an inner join based on the id and id - 1 where the part = part and item = item and country = country. This worked fine for me. It took the query from 55mins for 4 parts to 18 seconds. Just a small gain.

Comment: Nice! Glad you found a workable solution that had a big impact on the performance!